# IE9 - Mime-type mismatch - Object doesn't support property

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm playing around with a JQuery plugin called JRumble:  http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/

I setup a simple fiddle to test:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/4LP65/6/

You can see that the plugin is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but on IE9 I am getting some errors.

Took a screenshot of the IE Developers tool to show what it is referring to:

[image]

I copied the text in the console just in case that image is  hard to read:

```
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
4
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
4
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
4
SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/jackrugile/jRumble/master/demo/js/jquery.jrumble.1.3.min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch 
show
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'jrumble' 
show, line 26 character 2
```

When I looked up issues with `Object doesn't support property or method 'jrumble'` , some of the solutions suggested that this can be caused by an id or class name that is the same as a JavaScript variable name.  However, there are no conflicting names in my simple example and it is still not working in IE.

**Just from looking at the console, it seems the issue might be a mime-type mismatch that is preventing JRumble from being seen by IE.**

Is this indeed the problem? Does anyone know how to go about getting around this issue?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further troubleshoot this, go to the Network tab, start capturing, then reload the page. Find the script and go to its detailed view. Check the `content-type` response header and see what it is.

This problem can be circumvented by serving the file from your own server with the correct headers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kolink.  In the Network tab it lists this plugin as "text/plain" under the content type heading.  With a result of 304.  Is there a way to get IE to see the type as applicaton/javascript through JSFiddle?

Comment: Hmmm... I am using JQuery, so could I use the $.browser.msie to steer it away from the plugin with an if statement, then implement a different functionality for IE?

Comment: Ok, just implemented the if statement and that seems to work.  So given that I can't modify JSfiddles server I guess this will do for now.  Thanks!